# input null in datetime (C# and WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datepicker

I have a Datepicker named dob and a variable dt that is of type DateTime. to convert my datepicker input to DateTime I'm using ToDateTime conversion as follows

```
DateTime dt;
dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dob.Text);
```

and then store dt in a database with its data type in MySQL as datetime.

My problem is that if I do not pick a dateTime my program crashes. My error is "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

I tried  writing

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dob.Text))
{

       dt = null;
}
```

but dt cannot be null. Is there a way I can have dt as null and be stored as null in the table? Thank you ^^

Comment: Datepicker has a datetime? (Nullable) property selecteddate which you should use instead of the text.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: How do you write your data to the table?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `DateTime?`:

```
DateTime? dt;
// Other code
dt = null; // Will be possible
```

Comment: its working but previous i had input a " string fe = "01/01/1900 12:00:00 AM";
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(fe);" if the dob field was empty. So now instead of getting null in my database, I'm getting 01/01/1900